# Where can I find Android virtual device in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-virtual-device

It was easy to find Android Virtual Device in 1.0, but I cant find it in 3.0.

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

I tried looking on YouTube, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: What do you mean by virtual device, do you think on emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are pictures to help you quickly get the answer.
If you click in Tools in the toolbar, then choose AVD Manager as picture

[image: Tools-> AVD Manager]

Then you will see a prompt with Virtual Devices

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.0 you can find the virtual device under

> AVD Manager

directory.
you can find AVD Manager directery icon in toolbar of android studjo or you can find it by clicking on

> Tools and click on AVD Manager

and there an option will come to create a virtual device.[image]